# Distance between folders inside "Icon view" mode (Nautilus)

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, nautilus, icons, xfce

I'm using two different file managers, and there one annoying thing which I admit in Nautilus. On the picture below you can see how beautiful Thunar show "Icon view" and how it's look in Nautilus on the front side of image.

How can i customize that distance between folders in "Icon view" mode inside the Nautilus file manager?

I'm using xubuntu 14.04 LTS with xfce 4.12.

[image]

Comment: i noticed this too. If i define a higher zoom level icons are displayed in vertical line instead side by side

Comment: This has been reported on launchpad and marked as fixed for version 3.16 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/589433

Answer (score 1):

**You need at least Nautilus 3.16**, currently not installed by default in Vivid nor Wily and in versions prior 3.16, you can't customize this behaviour.

To install the GNOME staging PPA with Nautilus 3.16, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625244/upgrading-to-gnome-3-16/625250?s=2|0.4224#625250), you need **at least** 15.04 Vivid Vervet.