# How to upgrade to the latest GNOME version?

Tags: gnome, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 15.04. I installed GNOME on top of that. Now I am using GNOME Shell. I heard 3.16 has many improvement. I am thinking about upgrading. My question is that, if I upgrade to GNOME 3.16 will I be able to upgrade to the next version of Ubuntu (15.10) when it arrives?

Comment: I really don't need unity. I happened to install ubuntu and installed gnome when I came to know about it. I did a fair bit of configuration, setup environment for work. Don't want to loose any of that. Otherwise I would have reinstalled the gnome version. Is there any way I can remove unity completely?

Comment: it  will be better if you do fresh install [Ubuntu Gnome](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/GetUbuntuGNOME/Non-LTS), this version of ubuntu comes with gnome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gnome-shell for Ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/618019/gnome-shell-for-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: As I said I have made a hell lot of configuration on it, lots of files, etc. I remember installing ubuntu and later installed kde. Then somebody helped me remove gnome completely. Is there anyway to do something of that sort? Like removing unity and upgrading to gnome 3.16?

Comment: @A.B. no no not a duplicate.I have already installed gnome shell.

Comment: Ok, I have an answer for you.

Comment: 3.16 is still in development, you should know what you are doing because you might face issues, good luck

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Warning: this version is in development.**

You can install the latest version of GNOME with two PPAs:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Update the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Upgrade your system (avoid using `upgrade`, it can cause problems to the PPAs you just added):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or if you want to reinstall GNOME

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

---

To revert the upgrade install `ppa-purge`

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

and run the following commands, in this order:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Comment: Thank you @A.B. Since you are saying this version is still in development, I will hold back my urge to upgrade :). But is there any way I can remove unity session? I am good with the gnome shell.

Comment: In my case GNOME 3.16 runs fine on Ubuntu 15.04 and you can easily revert the installation. Maybe you should really install GNOME Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: May be I should, to avoid other complications :) Thank you everyone. This was my first post :)

Comment: it'll upgrade mu ubuntu to 18.04, cause I don't want it

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3.28.4. The latest release is 3.36.1 but after doing the above steps apt dist-upgrade still does not find any updates.

Comment: @Jiia I have the same issue with you.

Comment: This PPA is not updated since 2018, and this answer is not relevant for Ubuntu 18.04+.