# Running two different versions of Eclipse IDE and have them not grouping on the dock

Tags: 18.04, eclipse, ubuntu-dock

I am wondering if this is at all possible in Ubuntu 18.04 with Eclipse 2019-03 and Eclipse 2019-06. I am testing the new version in parallel to check for any issues we might have, before moving all developers over to it. I have two different `.desktop` files and both as favorites on the dock. When launched from their respective icons however, they both group on the older version. It would be a great quality of life improvement for me if I could have them on their own respective icons. It would be easier to switch correctly back and forth and a lot easier to see which version I'm currently in.

I have found [this older question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653702/startupwmclass-will-not-change-wm-class-of-eclipse-ide) about it, but it has no answer. The `xprop WM_CLASS` is the same for both versions

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Eclipse", "Eclipse"
```

As suggested in the old question, I haven't been able to find a `plugins.xml` with properties regarding the name of the application. Is there any other way to separate these windows or applications so that they don't group on the dock?

**Edit**
I tried adding the `--class` flag to the `Exec` part of the desktop file but it is not having any effect on the `WM_CLASS` variable.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 2019-06 Java 11
Type=Application
Exec=/home/simonc/jee-2019-06/eclipse/eclipse --class Eclipse2
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/simonc/jee-2019-06/eclipse/icon2.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse 2019-06 Java 11
Name[en_US]=Eclipse 2019-06 Java 11
StartupWMClass=Eclipse2
```

The result is still

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "Eclipse", "Eclipse"
```

Comment: See if this is helpful: https://askubuntu.com/q/1000818/480481

Comment: @pomsky While it definitely looks like a solution, it does not seem to work. The WM_CLASS property does not change to the provided class name.