# Installing GNOME 3.16 on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: gnome, updates, ppa

Can you please help me with installing GNOME 3.16 on Ubuntu 15.04?

I added https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3
to the repositories and installed "gnome", but I still have GNOME 3.14.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading to gnome 3.16](http://askubuntu.com/questions/625244/upgrading-to-gnome-3-16)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the  `https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging` ppa. It's the one with gnome 3.16

Answer (score 0):

To get **GNOME 3.16** you have to add gnome3-staging PPA.
Instruction for installation -> Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Choose **gdm** when asked.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo service gdm restart
```

Select **GNOME** from login screen.

If you get notified to perform a restart, you can do that.
Some say it is recommended, it's not necessary anyway.

Comment: Good one, upvoted =)