# Gnome 3.14 not showing tray

Tags: gnome, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

Hy there!
I just made a fresh install of Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 on a Dell Latitude E5450. I am fairly new to Gnome 3.X but I am pretty sure I am missing a tray... namely, I don't have any way to access the applications that minimise to tray (Spotify, Dropbox, Skype, etc). Is there anything I am missing?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be by default in a bar at the bottom in 3.14 (and older versions) - you can access it by pushing the mouse at the bottom of the screen (or pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or something), like the grey bit at the bottom of this screenshot - this also will contain notifications you get:

[image]

However, similar to the screenshot, you can move the status icons of Skype, Dropbox etc to the top bar by use of [GNOME shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) - e.g.:

- [Topicons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/)
- [TopTray](https://github.com/mjnaderi/TopTray) (similar but you should be able to re-size the icons)

N.B with 3.16 (unavailable by default on your Ubuntu version), it has been changed so by default the the notification appear in the calendar menu, and the status icons appear in the bottom left - see [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/gnome-316-released-with-new.html)

Comment: THANK YOU! For some reason the tray does not appear when I push the cursor to the bottom (or at least not every time) but the key combination did the trick. In my opinion this is a huge design flaw, how come they expect one person to find this? Anyway, it's an older version of Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

I have to write an answer, too =)

Update your GNOME to version 3.16 as describes [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/625250/367165).

With this version you have a small floating window in the lower right corner, which you can show if necessary. The behavior in GNOME 3.14 has always bothered me. GNOME 3.16 is also not optimal, but it is an improvement.